# Wordpress: Required Multiple Slugs for a single page (Not custom post)

Tags: wordpress, query-variables

I am creating a plugin. I want to pass parameters in URL or you can say I want multiple URLs for same page(But this will load same page **Not a Redirect**).
For example: 
http://www.ijmsbr.boxysolutions.com/publications-of-ijmsbr/?data=2016-11
I want this URL in this structure
http://www.ijmsbr.boxysolutions.com/publications-of-ijmsbr/2016-11/

and these will be multiple links like

- publications-of-ijmsbr/2016-11/
- publications-of-ijmsbr/2016-12/
- publications-of-ijmsbr/2017-01/

But all links should load this one page
publications-of-ijmsbr/

http://www.ijmsbr.boxysolutions.com/publications-of-ijmsbr/

this is my custom page. I want to get these parameters (/2016-11/, /2016-12/) on my page.

Comment: Use a Redirect plugin will do the same

Comment: But I said I don't want redirect. I want multiple urls should load one page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Resolved**

---

First we'll add filter to set query variables. Remember you've to call **flush_rewrite_rules()** each time when you'll add new variable in array. Once you've run flush_rewrite_rule function after that you can comment or delete this line.

```
function themeslug_query_vars( $qvars ) {
$qvars[] = 'jm_volume';
$qvars[] = 'jm_art_id';
$qvars[] = 'jm_author';
//flush_rewrite_rules();
return $qvars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'themeslug_query_vars' , 10, 1 );
```

After registration of query variables we can add **add_rewrite_rules** and assign to our URL like this. **Remember to call flush_rewrite_rules() function**

```
function add_rewrite_rules($aRules) {
$aNewRules = array(
    'publications-of-ijmsbr/article/(.*)?' => 'index.php?pagename=publications-of-ijmsbr&jm_art_id=$matches[1]',
    'publications-of-ijmsbr/author/(.*)?' => 'index.php?pagename=publications-of-ijmsbr&jm_author=$matches[1]',
    'publications-of-ijmsbr/(.*)?' => 'index.php?pagename=publications-of-ijmsbr&jm_volume=$matches[1]'
);
$aRules = $aNewRules + $aRules;
//flush_rewrite_rules();
return $aRules;
}
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```

Comment: Great answer, still works fine with the newest Wordpress (5.5)!